# My useQuery hook is refetching everytime its called. I thought it is suppose to hand back the cache?

Tags: react-query

I'm a little confused here. I thought react-query, when using useQuery will hand back 'cache' n subsequent calls to the same "useQuery". But everytime I call it it, it refetches and makes the network call.

Is this the "proper way" to do this? I figured it would just auto hand me the "cache" versions. I tried extending staleTime and cacheTime, neither worked. Always made a network call. I also tried initialData with the cache there.. didn't work.

SO, I am doing the following, but seems dirty.

Here is the what I have for the hook:

```
export default function useProducts ({
 queryKey="someDefaultKey", id
}){
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useQuery(
    [queryKey, id],
    async () => {
      const cachedData = await queryClient.getQueryData([queryKey, id]);

      if (cachedData) return cachedData;

      return await products.getOne({ id })
    }, {
        enabled: !!id
       }
  );
}
```

This is initiated like so:

```
  const { refetch, data } = useProducts(
      {
        id
      }
    }
  );
```

I call "refetch" with an onclick in two diff locations.. I'd assume after I retrieve the data.. then subsequent clicks will hand back cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m afraid there are multiple misconceptions here:

- react query operates on stale-while-revalidate, so it will give you data from the cache and then refetch in the background. You can customize this behavior by setting `staleTime`, which will tell the library how long the data can be considered fresh. No background updates will happen.
- when you call `refetch`, it will refetch. It’s an imperative action. If you don’t want it, don’t call refetch.
- you don’t need to manually read from the cache in the queryFn - the library will do that for you.

Comment: Quick additional question. Since react-query returns the cache and then does a "refetch" in background.... but lets say "n" number of "clicks" fire this particular query. Wouldn't it be less intrusive to do what I did and return cache, rather than reading cache in 'n' places to to determine to call "refetch"?

Comment: You usually set a staleTime to avoid excessive requests if that’s your use case. Requests that go out at the same tine are automatically deduped by react-query

Comment: thanks, but just an FYI. I set a staleTime of 60 seconds (60000) and clicked various items within that time, and they all "fired in the network" tab. So, i'm not sure its working as intended.

Comment: I can take a look if you create a codesandbox.